# Why do new invocations of this function create new scope chains and a new private variables?

Tags: javascript, closures, scope-chain

If we have this basic function (and its closures):

```
function counter(){
    var n = 0;
    return {
        count: function() {return n++},
        reset: function() {n = 0}
    };
}
```

Is *this* what's happening in memory? (basically a pointer to a function object and its scope chain)
[image: function diagram]
<sub>(source: [geraldleroy.com](http://www.geraldleroy.com/function-diagram.jpg))</sub>

Is the above diagram correct? If so, I'm not understanding why these two lines of code create two new scope chains and new private variables:

var c =  counter();

var d = counter();

It seems like both c and d would refer to the *original* function object and would use *its* scope chain.

I'm a little confused and would appreciate any insight on this that anyone can offer.

Thanks!

Comment: The term you're looking for is "closure".

Comment: Quick question: do you understand how function calls work in other, non-functional, languages? C for example? As in, do you know what a call stack (or activation record) is?

Comment: Hey there.  Thanks for responding.  Yup, I'm familiar with call stacks as used in the C language architecture. I guess I'm having a little trouble understanding the equivalent architecture in JavaScript (although I know that JavaScript isn't stack based).

Answer (score 1):

Scope chains do not really apply here. Look up 'execution context' and 'activation object' to understand what is happening when a function is invoked. See the brief summary of these concepts at http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core/

Your `return` statement includes an object literal. So each time `counter` is invoked a new object is created in memory.

Comment: Thanks for posting the link to Dmitry Soshnikov's JavaScript information.  I found his info to be extremely helpful!  It helped me to understand the answer to my question, which is: every time a function is invoked, a new execution context is created.  The new execution context includes three items: activation/variable object, scope reference and "this" value. Each new activation object contains it's own private copies of the outer function's local variables. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Java script is 'lexically scoped'. *This means that they run in the scope in which they are defined, not the scope from which they are executed.* You define 2 variables definitions that get the object returned by the function, hence you get 2 scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what is happening here, is that when you call function counter() - new private counter - n is created and an object which contains two functions that can access that private variable, so it can not be disposed of until your returned object is not destroyed. Also everything that is within your function is not bound to anything, meaning if your object that you are returning would be defined somewhere else and you would only return it's reference - this function would create new counter n and your object would now refer to new counter n, but the old one would be disposed of.